# Не открывается файл через вордпресс

Tags: php, wordpress

Подключаю файл SxGeo.php для определения страны пользователя.

```
<?php 
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
print($ip);
include("SxGeo.php");
$geo = new SxGeo('SxGeo.dat');
print($geo->getCountryId($ip));
?>
```

Но возникает ошибка на 56 строке

```
public function __construct($db_file ='SxGeo.dat', $type = SXGEO_FILE){
```

Ошибка:

```
Warning :  fopen(SxGeo.dat): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\user\Downloads\OSPanel\domains\wptest\wp-content\themes\samurai\SxGeo.php in line 56
```

Файлы находятся на одном уровне:
[image: de]
Попробовал сделать в обычном проекте без WP, всё заработало. Попробовал задать путь к файлу абсолютно, тоже не сработало, как можно это исправить?

Comment: get_template_directory() . '/SxGeo.php';

Comment: @Krya теперь фатальная ошибка :  Constant expression contains invalid operations in

Comment: Укажи правильный путь к файлу...

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `include("SxGeo.php");` используй `require_once get_stylesheet_directory(). '/SxGeo.php;';`

Или константу `TEMPLATEPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Название файла сделайте с нижним регистром и соответственно в коде тоже.